# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

**Error**:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
```

**Here is the code**:

```js
const result1 = (null || undefined) ?? 'OK'; 
console.log(result1); // 'OK'
```

It raises the **unexpected token error** when I run this program in `Node.js`

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: You're using too old a version. If my memory serves me correctly, it was added in node 14.

Comment: This was added in Node.js 14.0.0. What version are you running?

Comment: The first place you should always look when you get an error involving a new language feature is the compatibility chart in MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Code Snippets are executed in the browser of whoever reads the question. Trying to demonstrate failures that are particular to your specific environment by running code in the reader's environment doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 7):

The [*nullish coalescing operator*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-binary-logical-operators) was newly added in [ECMAScript 2020](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/), in June 2020 (about six months ago as of the date of the original question).

If you are using ECMAScript 2020 features in your code, make sure you use an ECMAScript implementation that fully implements ECMAScript 2020 ([or at least the features you are using](https://test262.report/browse/language/expressions/coalesce)).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are on Windows, [download the LTS or current](https://nodejs.org/en/#home-downloadhead).

After this reboot your machine and make sure in your package json you do not specify an `engine` that is less than 13 (optional)

```
{ "engines" : { "node" : ">14" } }
```

run your script

Comment: Turns out i had switched from node V18 to V14 to perform some tests.