# Unexpected token '?' on npm run start

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I am using npm version **12.22.3** in my Mac:

```
myuser@myuser-MacBook-Pro myproject-master % nvm ls      
->     v12.22.3
         system
default -> 12.22.3 (-> v12.22.3)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v12.22.3) (default)
stable -> 12.22 (-> v12.22.3) (default)
lts/* -> lts/hydrogen (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.12 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.21.3 (-> N/A)

lts/gallium -> v16.20.2 (-> N/A)

lts/hydrogen -> v18.18.0 (-> N/A)

myuser@myuser-MacBook-Pro myproject-master%
```

Trying to run npm on **IntelliJ**. But getting below error:

```
myuser@myuser-MacBook-Pro myproject-master % npm run start

> authserver@0.0.0 start /Users/myuser/Downloads/myproject-master
> concurrently --kill-others "npm run build-dev && npm run serve" "npm run watch"

/Users/myuser/Downloads/myproject-master/node_modules/concurrently/dist/src/command.js:78
                exitCode: exitCode ?? String(signal),
                                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myuser/Downloads/myproject-master/node_modules/concurrently/dist/src/index.js:4:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! authserver@0.0.0 start: `concurrently --kill-others "npm run build-dev && npm run serve" "npm run watch"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the authserver@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Is anyone aware about this error?

Comment: Node 12 doesn't support nullish coalescing (and is also [out of support](https://github.com/nodejs/release#release-schedule)): https://node.green/#ES2020-features--nullish-coalescing-operator-----

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/release#release-schedule

Comment: WTF? Why was this question closed?

Comment: @Fred It's a duplicate of other questions asked before. Did you look at the [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65396855/syntaxerror-unexpected-token) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68692038/how-to-solve-error-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)?

Comment: I am able to fix the issue by going on version 14.5.0 of node JS.

Comment: I was right in the middle of answering the question when it was deleted. This is just super annoying. I don't care for duplicates. I never understood SO's kink for marking something as a duplicate, when half of the times the mod didn't even look right into it and it's not an actual duplicate. And the other half doesn't matter anyways. ISO is not like Wikipedia, where people would have to maintain each article. So why even care for duplicates?